# Spring Forms and org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Spring Forms to bind an object to an HTML form.  The object already exists in my database so it is now being edited.

The problem is that when I try to update the object via AJAX or a full page request back to the server I am getting `org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException`.

I have tried `context.currentSession().saveOrUpdate(instance)` and `context.currentSession().update(instance)` on the DAO but neither work.

It seems that the hibernate `version` column is causing this problem because when I add the version column to the spring binding.

`<sf:hidden id="myobject-id" path="myobject.version"/>`

I am able to save, however, if I save via AJAX and then save again via a full save reload I see the StaleObjectStateException again because the version has changed again via the AJAX save (different to the one now in the form).

I don't want to have to bind the version column to the form anyway, there must be a more elegant way of doing this.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried merge()?  merge() will bind the object back to the session.  I believe you need to have the entity within a session for it be updated.